# Rails - How to check the time of the last DB update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a ruby on rails app backed by sqlite3 DB. The DB is backed up to cloud periodically. As an optimization it will be nice to perform the cloud backup only if the DB was updated (any update to any row of any table) since the last backup cycle. What would such a rails query look like? I can check the timestamp on the sqlite3 file, but would like to know if Rails provides such a mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has no such mechanism.

Instead of the timestamp, you could read the file change counter at offset 24 of the [header of the database file](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header).

(In WAL mode, changes might be written only to the WAL file, so neither the file timestamp nor the change counter would be guaranteed to work.)